# Convert Money/Currency to Cent and vice versa

Tags: java

I am trying to store cent (int) in database due to round issue.

What is the algorithm to convert Double money value to cent and vice versa?

Comment: A little more details/context would help.

Comment: Can you provide an example double storing a monetary value?

Comment: money to cent? From dollars? You mean, multiply by 100 and round?

Comment: Do you know you should never store monetary values in floating point types?

Comment: @JanDvorak it is even easier my way if he always has whole cents

Comment: You're doing this all wrong from start to finish. You shouldn't be using floating-point in the first place in the code, you should be using `BigDecimal`, and you shouldn't be using ints or cents in the database, you should be using `DECIMAL(9,2)`, changing `9` as appropriate to your case. Please don't underestimate or disregard this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the feedbacks and mark down.This is a simple question but with so many arguments.  NoSQL db i am using do not has any decimal (9,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following `double` value,

```
double allTheMoney = 123.54; // as in $123 + 54 cents
```

You can get it in cents using,

```
int allCents = (int)(allTheMoney * 100);
// or using long
long allCents = Math.round(allTheMoney * 100);
```

Comment: Alas, the inevitable race to be the first with the answer.

Comment: @ITroubs neither one should have answered IMO. As in, help vampire alert.

Comment: Read comment on @ITroubs answer. It applies to yours too.

Comment: Updated to show @ITroubs' suggestion of `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is fast and easy:

```
double val = 1.45;
int cents = (int)(val * 100);
```

or

```
int cents = (int)Math.round(val*100);
```

Comment: This doesn't round. Because of the way floating point values are stored, the actual double value could be 1.4499999 and this would convert it to 144 cents.

Comment: I know. that is also the reason why no one should work with double when it comes to money...

Comment: So use `(val + 0.005D) * 100D` if I recall correctly.

Comment: @LeeMeador Why not Math.round(val*100)? This would be the "better" way..

Comment: That would be ok but slower, I suspect. The reason this is a problem is that when we represent 1/5 (0.2) as a binary fraction, we get `0.011001100110...` (0110 repeating) which can't be represented in a finite number of bits. A double stores its value as a binary fraction and 20 cents is 1/5 dollar and that (or 'multiples' like 40, 10, and 5) generates this sort of problem and bits get lost.